# if else wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$date = date('H');

if($date >= 22 && $date <= 04){ 
    echo 'это ночь';
}
else if($date >= 05 && $date <= 11){
    echo 'это утро';
}
else if($date >= 12 && $date <= 16){
    echo 'это день';
}
else if($date >= 17 && $date <=21){
    echo 'это вечер';
}
```

Данный код не работает в wordpress, `date()` менял на `current_time()`, не помогло.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: `echo день';`  => `echo 'день'`;

Comment: прошу прощения, допустил опечатку, в исходном коде все правильно написано

Comment: скажите, а в данном контексте, файле, или что это, мне не понятно, просто без этих if echo вообще что-то выводит? К примеру echo $date; ?
И вообще есть условие elseif без проблов он тут по идеи уместнее

Comment: Пробовали выводить значение $date? Что значит неработает?

Comment: у меня просто предположение, что там буферизированный блок через ob_start или что-то подобное и там вообще ничего не выводитсяю

Comment: вне условия echo $date выводит текущее время

Comment: Условия гляньте: что значит: 04 цифра 4 кроме того все-равно если это не php7 то вам должен быть результат.

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, date() берет время с сервера, можно ли сделать так, чтобы у пользователя отображалось время исходя из его часовой зоны?

Comment: О временной зоне посетителя может знать только браузер. Соответственно если вы не сообщите через JS об этом серверу - не узнаете какая временная зона у посетителя. Ну и естественно он может прикинуться толстым шлангом и указать неправильную зону

Comment: Как минимум в первых двух условиях должно быть не &&, а ||. Сами подумайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну возможно проблема в том что число не может быть одноверемено больше 22 и меньше 4-х:

`if($date >= 22 && $date <= 04){`

Рекомендую использовать `date('G')` которая вернет час без нуля.

Ну и небольшой пример проверки:

```
function whatTheTime($date){
    if($date >= 22 || $date <= 4){ 
        return 'это ночь';
    }
    else if($date >= 5 && $date <= 11){
        return 'это утро';
    }
    else if($date >= 12 && $date <= 16){
        return 'это день';
    }
    else if($date >= 17 && $date <=21){
        return 'это вечер';
    }
}

foreach(range(0, 24) as $hour){
    echo $hour.' - ';
    echo whatTheTime($hour);
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96ccfb6c32991db864a2a4b2498fffa19512681a)

Answer (score 1):

Самая обычная синтаксическая ошибка.
`echo день';` => `echo 'день';`

Что бы их избежать установите редактор который знает синтаксис PHP.

Из бесплатных:

- Notepad ++
- Atom
- Microsoft Code
- Brackets

Для некоторых могут понадобиться плагины.

Comment: опечатку допустил в вопросе, в исходном коде echo выводится в кавычках